Show live clock in bash in front of command prompt
I am looking for a way to show the current live time/clock in bash before the command prompt. What I researched so far, there are some possibilities for that. E.g. I know the bash variable PS1 can be customized with \t but that only updates the clock every time you press enter.
For example one can put this in ~/.bashrc what I currently have:
PS1='[\t] \[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$ \[\033[00m\]'

But that is not what I want - my goal is something like shown here which uses something like following code what I also have in my ~/.bashrc:
while sleep 1;do tput sc;tput cup $(($(tput lines)-1)) 0;printf [`date +%H:%M:%S`];tput rc;done &

This is nearly perfect for me, the only problem with this code is, it works well until I send SIGINT e.g. by pressing control+c. I would like a solution like that which does not stop the clock (or that particular subshell where the clock runs) when pressing control+c. I want to be able to use control+c like usual in bash.
To be clear, I also found a solution for this with zsh but I would like to do that with bash if anyhow possible. And I do not want the clock to be shown elsewhere in the terminal, it should be shown live at the prompt, so I can e.g. even scroll back up the terminal and look at what time/second exactly I issued a command.
Thanks in advance!

Let's work through what that would require in a shell like bash which doesn't support live update of the prompt: first, you'd need to figure where the prompt is. That might not appear too hard to do at first glance - just get the current line where the cursor, is, and adjust the column to a suitable location. Then write the timestamp there using the code you already have.

Now comes the complication: what happens when have a multiline command? The code will happily trash the displayed command in each successive line as the cursor moves down. So you might think - let's just get the cursor line only when the prompt is displayed. That will still run into trouble if you ever scroll. So now you have two mutually incompatible requirements.

At that point, you might consider either (a) using existing features like timestamped history (since you say you want to know when a command was executed, that seems a better fit, since it will persist those timestamps even after you close the terminal), or (b) just using a shell like zsh which supports the advanced feature you want. It's like asking how do you independently actuate all 4 wheels of a 2WD - you don't, you get a 4WD instead.

Not what you're asking but e.g. screen can be configured to show the time in a caption line that's always visible, so you can get the time in the corner of the terminal. It wouldn't be in the prompt, and it would take a full line, but then again, you can put other things there, too.

My Basta project provides something like this. There isn't a changing clock in your command line, but in a protected status line at the bottom of the screen.
The clock updates work by forking a process which sends a SIGALRM signal to the parent Bash process every 15 seconds. In the trap handler for this signal, we re-draw the status line with the current clock value.
A status line with the clock, date and working directory lets me have an uncluttered prompt (just $ ).
I use Basta together with the cdlog directory navigation system.
